# what am I missing in this datetostr conversion?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I thought the new dxDateTimeWheelPicker from devexpress was kind of cute so I tried to see how it works. I tried to see if the label will display the month when I turned the month wheel but I get incompatible types error (DateTime and string).

```
procedure TForm3.dxDateTimeWheelPicker2PropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
var
myDate : TDateTime;
begin
myDate := datetimetostr(dxDateTimeWheelPicker2.DateTime);
label1.Caption := formatdatetime('mm', myDate);
end;
```

What am I missing here ? What must I do to make this work ?

Comment: What do you expect `datetimetostr()` to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a `TDateTime` variable:

```
var
  myDate : TDateTime;
```

You are then trying to assign to this variable the result of a function that converts a `TDateTime` to a **String**:

```
myDate := datetimetostr(dxDateTimeWheelPicker2.DateTime);
```

So of course you get an incompatible types error, because a `TDateTime` is not assignment compatible with a `String`.  But for this exercise you only need the `TDateTime` value itself so this intermediate string conversion is entirely unnecessary.  All you need is this:

```
myDate := dxDateTimeWheelPicker2.DateTime;
label1.Caption := formatdatetime('mm', myDate);
```

In this case you could even do without the `myDate` variable itself if you wished:

```
label1.Caption := formatdatetime('mm', dxDateTimeWheelPicker2.DateTime);
```